# VB.net Sort Panel Controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

There are panel inside my panels and panels inside button/label. I am creating these panels dynamically.

I want to move and align these panels in a draggable way as in the examples, but I have no way yet.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5zWS.png)

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyfGw.gif)

{Pictures are not mine}

Can you help me at least?

Comment: And how does this relate to the C programming language? Please don't add irrelevant tags. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Excuse me! I am using translate , it is so. I was want to write C#.I EDİTED the post.

Comment: Those "panels" should be UserControls.  You have to tell us which platform: WPF, WinForms, Web?  And attempt some kind of code.

Comment: I was already using user control and my platform is WinForms.

Comment: The title say "VB .net", but it is tagged as C#.

Comment: No where in your post did you mention UserControls, only Panels.  What part are you having problems with?  Show that code.

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/401949/controls-and-libraries/tree-list/feature-center/drag-and-drop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example using Labels in a FlowLayoutPanel.  The Labels are added whenever an entry is put into the TextBox and the Button is clicked.  You can then drag and drop the Labels in the FlowLayoutPanel to change their position:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        FlowLayoutPanel1.AllowDrop = True
        FlowLayoutPanel1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown
        Me.AcceptButton = Button1
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddEntry(ByVal entry As String)
        Dim lbl As New Label
        lbl.Text = entry
        lbl.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        lbl.Margin = New Padding(3)
        AddHandler lbl.MouseMove, AddressOf lbl_MouseMove
        AddHandler lbl.QueryContinueDrag, AddressOf lbl_QueryContinueDrag
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl)
    End Sub

    Private Sub lbl_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
            lbl.BackColor = Color.Orange
            lbl.DoDragDrop(lbl, DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length > 0 Then
            AddEntry(TextBox1.Text.Trim)
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox1.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub lbl_QueryContinueDrag(sender As Object, e As QueryContinueDragEventArgs)
        If e.Action = DragAction.Drop OrElse e.Action = DragAction.Cancel Then
            Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
            lbl.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.DragEnter
        e.Effect = If(e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(Label)), DragDropEffects.All, DragDropEffects.None)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles FlowLayoutPanel1.DragOver
        Dim pt As Point = FlowLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
        Dim overLabel As Label = FlowLayoutPanel1.GetChildAtPoint(pt)
        If Not IsNothing(overLabel) Then
            Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(GetType(Label)), Label)
            If Not lbl Is overLabel Then
                Dim newIndex As Integer = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.IndexOf(overLabel)
                If newIndex <> FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.IndexOf(lbl) Then
                    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(lbl, newIndex)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Program in action:

[image]